# Configuration distribution

Tags: java, configuration

I'm looking for existing solutions to the problem of distributing configurations to Java applications.

A simple example: There would be a master application (a configuration server) C that manages all the configurations. When an application A is started, it registers to the server C and gets the configuration it needs to work properly. Obviously, each application should be authenticated by the server and the server authenticated by the applications, possibly using certificates.
The server holds the configuration for each application.

I know that it should not be difficult to design such an architecture from scratch but I am interested to know if there are existing solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of Apache projects

ZooKeeper http://zookeeper.apache.org/, for distributed configuration and coordination

Commons Configuration http://commons.apache.org/configuration/ which is widely used, but I'm not sure if it supports mutual authentication (you would use the database configuration source)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at these projects.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider building a solution on top of [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), which is an open-source, command-line utility that can download a file from a URL and write that file to standard output. For example, executing `curl -sS http://someHost/file.cfg` will download `file.cfg` from the specified web server. The `-sS` options instruct Curl to print error messages but not any any progress diagnostics. Curl supports many protocols including HTTP, FTP, LDAP, and their secure variants.

A Java application could: (1) execute `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -sS ...")` to use Curl to download the contents of a configuration file from somewhere; And then (2) parse that with whatever configuration parser you like.

To save you re-inventing the wheel for (1), I suggest you download the source code of [Config4J](http://www.config4star.org/), and look at the implementation of the `org.config4j.Util.execCmd()` method.

Comment: You don't need a third party software to download files over http in Java, this is supplied out-of-the-box by standard libraries, see for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html